# SQL SSMS return most frequent value for each personal id

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is a similar question on here but for Mysql.
I need to create a new column in my table `dbo.table`, that returns the most frequent fruit that a customer bought. `P_id` and `Fruit_bought` already exist, but I want the third column `favourite_fruit` (as seen below):

```
p_id        Fruit_bought   Favourite_fruit
7740319     Apple          Apple
976942      Pear           Pear
976942      Pear           Pear
7740319     Apple          Apple
7740319     Pear           Apple
976942      Banana         Pear
5674352     Pear           Pear
5674352     Pear           Pear
5674352     Pear           Pear
```

Both columns are VARCHAR. How do I go about this in sql? I'm a newbie but I'm presuming alter table?

Comment: You want to add a column to a table or add a column to the result of a select query?

Comment: This isn't somethnig you want to add as a new column to your table; you'd be forever chasing your tail as you would have to update *every* row for an ID whenever 1 row in `INSERT`ed, `UPDATE`d or `DELETE`d. You want a `VIEW` here.

Comment: What happens if someone has bought equal amounts of different fruits?

Comment: @Larnu, In this case I won't be adding or taking away any more info from the data, and just want a static answer, so a new column to my table would be fine. Also the data set is so large I won't need to worry about getting equal amounts of fruit

Comment: Saying that if it's easier to do it as the results of a selected query, happy to do that @SalmanA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you just want to create a ***report*** about the ***favorite fruit per person*** you can use this query:

```
with cte as (
    select p_id, fruit_bought, row_number() over (partition by p_id order by count(*) desc) as rn
    from t
    group by p_id, fruit_bought
)
select p_id, fruit_bought as favorite_fruit
from cte
where rn = 1
```

Comment: If I then want to write a query to delete the dublicate P_id rows, can I refer to t2 as a table? @Salman A

Comment: delete the duplicate? Like deleting from the table using `DELETE` statement or do you just want to hide those rows?

Comment: I'm not sure if I need to delete them, but I want to be able to export the data set into excel and at the moment there are too many entries to fit. So I want to delete/hide the duplicate rows saying what each Id's favourite fruits are. To export into excel I think I would have to delete?

Comment: So basically you want a list of faviorite fruit per person from that data, that you can opy-paste into excel?

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm after

Comment: See revised answer.

Comment: Thank you that worked really well, would you be able to explain the change you made from the first draft to the second draft please?

Comment: The original query returned all the rows in your original table + favorite fruit column. This one uses grouping to compress multiple rows per person into one row per person which is what you actually/presumably want.

Comment: Thank you @Salman A your help has been much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Like I mentioned in the comments, I wouldn't do this as a computed column as you'll be forever chasing your tail. You say the data won't ever change, but that is *never* true; I've heard that excuse too many times, and weeks/months later I get the same thing "I know I said it wouldn't change, but it has, and now the data is wrong. How do you have these values update automatically?".

As such, use a `VIEW`. Within the `VIEW`, I use a windowed `COUNT` to find out how many of each fruit was purchased by each person, and then ise `FIRST_VALUE` to get the favourite fruit. In the event of a tie, the first fruit alphabetically is returned. Full repro below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (p_id int,
                            Fruit_bought varchar(20));
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (p_id, Fruit_bought)
VALUES (7740319,'Apple'),
       (976942,'Pear'),
       (976942,'Pear'),
       (7740319,'Apple'),
       (7740319,'Pear'),
       (976942,'Banana'),
       (5674352,'Pear'),
       (5674352,'Pear'),
       (5674352,'Pear');
GO

CREATE VIEW dbo.YourView AS

    WITH Counts AS(
        SELECT p_id,
               Fruit_bought,
               COUNT(Fruit_bought) OVER (PARTITION BY P_id, Fruit_bought) AS Times_bought
        FROM dbo.YourTable)
    SELECT p_id,
           Fruit_bought,
           FIRST_VALUE(Fruit_bought) OVER (PARTITION BY P_id ORDER BY Times_bought DESC, Fruit_Bought ASC) AS Favourite_fruit
    FROM Counts;
GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourView;
GO

DROP VIEW dbo.YourView;
DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

Comment: Using the windowed count would I need to list all the 'values'?

Comment: List all what values, @GraceTrif ? The windowed `COUNT` is just on the columns `P_id` and `Fruit_bought`. It doesn't list *any* values.

Comment: Lines 5-13 of your answer have the 'values' listed, would I need to list them all as there are most (this was just a snapshot of the data)

Comment: ... That is an `INSERT` statement for your sample data, @GraceTrif ...